# How to implement teradata dbprovider in spring.net?

Tags: spring, teradata

I have an .net application that currently uses spring dbprovider to connect to an oracle database.

The database is now being migrated from Oracle to Teradata. I am new to Spring and Teradata does not seem to be in the default list of dbprovider present in Spring.

Is there any way to add the teradata configuration in spring. If so please provide me the step by step method.

Currently this is the connection string being used in Spring .Net:

```
<db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="OracleClient-2.0" connectionString="Data Source=${db.server};User Id=${db.user};Password=${db.password};" />
```

I believe it is the data access object for 10g

Could you please let me know how to create a DSN for teradata in Spring .Net Currently I have a DataAccess.xml page with the configuration:

```
<db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="Teradta" connectionString="Data Source=${db.server};User Id=${db.user};Password=${db.password};" /> - <object id="adoTemplate" type="Spring.Data.Generic.AdoTemplate, Spring.Data"> <property name="DbProvider" ref="dbProvider" /> </object>
```

Comment: Are you using JDBC currently or a different client provider?

Comment: Currently this is the connection string being used in Spring .Net <db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="OracleClient-2.0" connectionString="Data Source=${db.server};User Id=${db.user};Password=${db.password};" /> I believe it is the data access object for 10g

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to install the Teradata ODBC driver, create a DSN, and use the Spring.Net ODBC 1.1 or ODBC 2.0 DBProvider.

**EDIT:**

The web server will need the DSN created. Whether you use a single 'service' account for the application or individual user accounts (which you will need to provide their credentials in your Spring.Net connection) is a decision for you and/or your company to arrive at.

Comment: Thank you so much fo this information Could you please let me know how to create a DSN for teradata in Spring .Net Currently I have a DataAccess.xml page with the configuration  <db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="Teradta" connectionString="Data Source=${db.server};User Id=${db.user};Password=${db.password};" /> 
- <object id="adoTemplate" type="Spring.Data.Generic.AdoTemplate, Spring.Data">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="dbProvider" /> 
  </object>

Comment: and a web.config file with the following configuration <databaseSettings>
    <!-- DEV -->
    <add key="db.server" value="NWDEV"/>
    <add key="db.user" value="dm_repl"/>
    <add key="db.password" value="dm_repl"/>

    <!-- UAT -->
    <!--add key="db.server" value="NWD1"/>
    <add key="db.user" value="MD"/>
    <add key="db.password" value="MD1234"/-->

    <!-- PROD -->
    <!--<add key="db.server" value="NWP1"/>
    <add key="db.user" value="ZNWDATA"/>
    <add key="db.password" value="planet"/>-->

  </databaseSettings>

Comment: The issue is this application will be used by multiple users on a network in that case will creating a DSN be the best choice? If so do I need to create it in the web server

Comment: sorry data access connection is .Net <db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="OracleClient-2.0" connectionString="Data Source=${db.server};User Id=${db.user};Password=${db.password};" />

Comment: See my edit in response to your question about the DSN location.

Comment: Hi Rob I tried the above method by installing the driver and creating a dsn then added it to spring using both 1.1 and 2.0 db provider but this did not work. I got the error message from spring as unable to load the driver. Is there any technology similar so that I can replace Spring.net? I believe spring.net does not support teradata?